# Change Background Color of a card_item.xml with ItemModel class in GridView

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a gridview with multiples card_items.xml (CardView), and onitemclick I'd like to change the background of it, I tried changing the view setBackGround...but it was not right because when I was selecting one of the card_item in gridview another one was selected too. Please Some help!!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Friend, thank you, I solved my problem it was a simple noob problem my layout manager was wrong. Thank you!